# Creating time from php variables

Tags: php

Echoing variables I'm getting correct values, but creating a date  - something is wrong.

```
echo $d;  // 0
echo $e;  // 0

$date = date("H-i", strtotime($d."-".$e));

echo $date; // 1-0
```

I expected `0-0`

Any help

Comment: Check what you are attempting to format with date(): `var_dump(strtotime($d."-".$e));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `0-0` is not actually valid, you must supply either a valid date or time formatted string. Some examples being `2018-01-26` and `10:10:10`. There are some shortcuts you can take, maybe checkout the manual for this information (links below). Currently you will find that `false` is being returned from `strtotime('0-0')` and when given to `date()` will probably default to the current time.

**Fix** by replacing `-` in your argument for `strtotime()` with the colon `:`.

```
php > echo date('H-i', strtotime('0:0'));
00-00
```

Not exactly your expectation, but since `H` and `i` will always return a string that is of length `2` its as close as you can get. The manual states "with leading zeros", links provided again.

- [strtotime() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- [date() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)